# Linker error when including header in files other than main.cpp

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I'm trying to add some utility functions and global variables to my code in such a way that I can be able to use them in every class I want in my project. I would like to use a .hpp file for the definitions end a .cpp file for the implementation.

This is a summary of these two files:

```
// This is Utilities.hpp
#ifndef utilities_hpp
#define utilities_hpp


namespace utils {

    int global_variable1;

    int global_variable2;

    void utility_function1(...);

    void utility_function2(...);

    void utility_function3(...);
}

#endif /* utilities_hpp */
```

and the implementation:

```
// This is Utilities.cpp
#include "Utilities.hpp"


namespace utils {

    void utility_function1(...) {
        // Some code
    }


    void utility_function2(...) {
        // Some code
    }


    void utility_function3(...) {
        // Some code
    }

}
```

Other than my `main.cpp` file I have two other classes. My `main.cpp` file includes `Class1.hpp` header that includes `Class2.hpp` header.

Now I thought that I could put another `#include "Utilities.hpp"` in `Class1.hpp` or `Class2.hpp` without any problems since I've used the guards in that header. The thing is that when I try to do that the linker throws me this error: `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and I can't understand why or what to do to solve it.

I'm using Xcode 8.3 on a macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

I hope I was able to explain my problem, thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Does it give more detailed output? Also, try to clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've violated the One Definition Rule.  `global_variable1` and `global_variable2` should be declared `extern` in your header and defined in exactly one translation unit (probably Utilities.cpp).

You've defined global variables in a header that gets included in multiple translation units, so there's a `utils::global_variable1` defined in main.cpp, and one in Utilities.cpp.  When it comes to link time, the linker has no way to know which `global_variable1` to use, so it throws an error.

To fix it, add the `extern` keyword to your declarations and add a definition in "Utilities.cpp":

Utilities.hpp:

```
// This is Utilities.hpp
#ifndef utilities_hpp
#define utilities_hpp


namespace utils {

    extern int global_variable1;
  //^^^^^^ <-----HERE
    extern int global_variable2;
  //^^^^^^ <-----HERE
    void utility_function1(...);

    void utility_function2(...);

    void utility_function3(...);
}

#endif /* utilities_hpp */
```

Utilities.cpp:

```
// This is Utilities.cpp
#include "Utilities.hpp"

namespace utils {

    int global_variable1;  //<---- Definitions added
    int global_variable2;

    void utility_function1(...) {
        // Some code
    }

    void utility_function2(...) {
        // Some code
    }

    void utility_function3(...) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! But can you explain why is this happening?I thought that the use of the `#ifndef utilities_hpp #define utilities_hpp #endif` safeguard would protect against problems like this

Comment: `#ifndef` include guards prevent a header from being include more than once _in a single translation unit_.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that my header has been included in more that one `.cpp` file and so my global variables have been declared more than once. Am I right?

Comment: Correct.  Though the issue isn't the variables being _declared_ multiple times, but rather them being _defined_ multiple times.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `extern` keyword on your global variables in your header.  As a result, you're defining them, which results in multiple definitions when you include the header in two different source modules.

Once you add the `extern` in the header file (`extern int global_variable1;`), you'll need to add the definition in your .cpp file where you also define your functions.