# Linker error: undefined reference to function from header file

Tags: c++, linker

I *did* try to find my specific issue, but the closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143833/linker-error-when-including-header-in-files-other-than-main-cpp) where the issue was with global variables.

I need make a lexer header file along with it's `cpp` file to use in `main.cpp`. here are the two lexer files:

```
// lexer.hpp
#ifndef LEXER_HPP
#define LEXER_HPP
// Some include files, not really relevant

namespace interpreter
{
    namespace lex
    {
        enum class TokType : char;
        typedef std::vector<std::pair<TokType, std::string>> TokenList;
        typedef std::pair<TokType, std::string> Token;
        TokenList tokenizeString(std::string tokStr);
    } // namespace lex
} // namespace interpreter

#endif
/* --------------------------------------*/
// lexer.cpp
// Again, some not-really-necessary include files
#include "lexer.hpp"
using namespace interpreter::lex;

enum class TokType : char {/* Stuff */};
TokenList tokenizeString(std::string tokStr) {/* Stuff*/};
```

When I use this stuff in `main.cpp` and compile, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3XtuwW.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `interpreter::lex::tokenizeString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Clearly, something is wrong with my function, but I cannot for the life of me figure out *what* is actually wrong.

Here's some other information if you need it:

- I turned my `lexer.cpp` into a `.o` file. Whether I use the `.cpp` file or the `.o` file does not make a difference, though.
- How I compiled `main.cpp`: `g++ -o main main.cpp lexer.o`
- `lexer.hpp`, `lexer.cpp`, `lexer.o` and `main.cpp` are all in the same directory.

Comment: You have declared tokenizeString and the compiler have found it. But have you actually defined the function in a .cpp file that is linked in?

Comment: Yes, the definition is in `lexer.cpp` which I compile along with `main.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
TokenList interpreter::lex::tokenizeString(std::string tokStr)
{
    /* Stuff*/
}
```

or this

```
namespace interpreter { namespace lex {
    TokenList tokenizeString(std::string tokStr)
    {
        /* Stuff*/
    }
} }
```

Although you've said `using namespace interpreter::lex;` that doesn't mean that newly defined names get added to the `interpreter::lex` namespace.

Comment: I generally don't like using `using namespace`, the only reason I did this time was that I needed to use the `enum` values a lot and writing `interpreter::lex::TokType::Thing` made code really long. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 use either of the two options I've given above. They are compatible with `using namespace ...`