# Function inside namespace in header file, declaration with 'using' in cpp file not compiling

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, using

In `myfunction.h`, I declare the function `myFunction()` inside the namespace `MyNamespace`:

```
namespace MyNamespace{
  void myFunction();
}
```

In `myfunction.cpp`, I include the implementation:

```
#include "myfunction.h"

void MyNamespace::myFunction(){
   std::cout<<"My function"<<std::end;
}
```

Everything compiles fine.

If instead in the `.cpp`, I write:

```
using namespace MyNamespace;

void myFunction(){
   std::cout<<"My function"<<std::end;
}
```

I get an "Undefined Symbol" error during linking. Why?

If instead of a function, I declare a class in the header file, and the implementation of a method of that class in the `.cpp` file, I have no issue.

Comment: `MyNamespace::myFunction()` No return type. You sure this file's getting compiled?

Comment: Once I add the missing `void` I can't reproduce. Mind you, I wouldn't have been able to reproduce without the missing `void`. I'd get completely different errors.

Comment: Or would I? Maybe my compiler's a bit smarter or compiling to a different C++ Standard. Could you add the compiler command line to the question?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the void...

Comment: It is a file inside a much larger project compiled by cmake, so I do not have a compiler command line to provide, but thanks  for helping!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linker error: undefined reference to function from header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979582/linker-error-undefined-reference-to-function-from-header-file) (The gist of the accepted answer is that although you write the `using namespace whatever`, the functions you define won't actually get added to that namespace still)

Comment: @medicrevegetable This is indeed the same question. Thanks for your answer, but then why are these functions not added to the namespace then? Also, the real example is with three nested namespaces. If I do use namespace MyNamespace1::MyNamespace2 and declare the function MyNamespace3::myFunction then it compiles without issues. So what is the difference then for the compiler? Thanks!